# Error connecting to multiple keyspaces in Spring Data Cassandra 4.0.5

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

```
Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource \
  [learn/multiple/database/configuration/SerenoKeyspaceConfig.class]: \
  No matching factory method found on class [learn.multiple.database.configuration.SerenoKeyspaceConfig]: \
  factory bean 'serenoKeyspaceConfig'; factory method 'cassandraTemplate()'. \
  Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
```

This error is coming with spring data version 4.0.5 but same code works perfectly in 3.3.4 version

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing a few details. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. For guidance, see stackoverflow.com/tour and stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to Cassandra from a Spring Data app, you specify a single keyspace in the configuration.

To connect to other keyspaces, you need to fully qualify the table you are connecting to by specifying both the keyspace name and table name in the CQL query.

For example, to get all the users in the `users` table in the `appks` keyspace:

```
    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        String cql = "SELECT * FROM appks.users";
        return cassandraTemplate.select(cql, User.class);
    }
```

To get the details of a specific customer in another keyspace called `eshop`:

```
    @Override
    public Customer findById(String id) {
        String cql = "SELECT * FROM eshop.customers WHERE id=?";
        return cassandraTemplate.selectOne(cql, Customer.class, id);
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, but i am using spring-data-repository & using inbuilt methods